# How to import all product data from magento 1.4.2 to 1.9.0

Tags: magento, csv, import, export, e-commerce

How to import all product data from magento 1.4.2 to 1.9.0

I have exported the csv file from magnento 1.4.2 but when i am trying to import in magento 1.9.0 it shows the following error :

Not found attributes: brand_name, ean, mpn, delivery_eta, is_iceimport please check you default attribute set.

Comment: Perhaps you can post the beginning of the file - that way people might know how to help you?

Comment: jensd : http://awesomescreenshot.com/0ea3ytrv29

Here the screenshot of my file

Comment: Perhaps as some inline code and not as an external link...

Comment: Do you have any idea to jump magento 1.4.2 t0 1.9.0 ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to create the missing custom attributes and assign them to the correct attribute set in your new installation.  It important they are of the same type with the same value(s) as your 1.4.2 store.  If you still have access to the old store, go to admin and;

Catalog > Attributes > Manage Attributes

from the top menu.  Find each attribute and copy the settings to your new installation.

Comment: There is any way for export/import attributes?

Comment: there are some database tricks - but so much has changed from 1.4.2 to 1.9 it would be WAY more trouble than it's worth. 

If you create the attributes themselves but dont want to create all the values, go and have a look at Magmi, this has a setting to create the values if they dont exist (but that attribute still needs to exist first)

Comment: I have hundreds of attributes in magneto 1.4.2 , So i'll have to create each attributes manually.but i don't want to do that.

Comment: you could remove the columns from your csv if you dont use those attributes of course....

Comment: could you provide more detail?  whats the error message?

Answer (score 0):

I think to buy extension like following is best solution for this.

http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/bolasevich/extension/2193/import-+-export-bulk-product-attributes--attribute-sets--attribute-options--multiple-attributes

As it supports both Magento version you have specified

Comment: There is any extension free of coast ??

Comment: I think no free extension available for this